# How to make Facebook app page invisible so it doesn't reveal identify of our users to their friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-social-plugins, privacy

My site has Facebook Connect to help users with registration and to do this we had to create a Facebook app. And on my Facebook app page, I noticed that it shows list of user's friends who also connected to our site using Facebook Connect. How can I take this down so that we don't reveal the identity of our users who connect to the website with Facebook Connect? In fact, I would like to make the Facebook app page invisible altogether since we don't need it. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?